# How to root Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-I9500 with build XXUBMH1?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-4

The latest build for Samsung Galaxy S4 in South Africa is [XXUBMH1](http://www.samsungupdate.com/android-updates/update-samsung-galaxy-s4-gt-i9500-to-android-4-2-2-xxubmh1). I followed [this guide to rooting S4s](http://www.oneclickroot.com/phone/how-to-root-samsung-galaxy-s4/) but it doesn't work on this build.

- How can I root this phone, preferably without having to load a different version of the firmware first?
- (Bonus) How can I find such information without trawling through many pages of discussions on `forums.xda-developers.com`?

If it's relevant, I'm running Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: It those "standard" hacking tools like towelroot and framaroot and such, aren't working for you, you could try doing it the manual way:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2684210

Answer (score 0):

I found this application quite useful https://towelroot.com/ download and run on your device and it roots your device for you. Its been recommended by XDA.I ran it on my s4 I9505 and worked perfectly.